# strong will or strong wills?

Tags: nouns, word-usage, articles

Idiomatically we do say "a strong will". But can we say "strong wills"? The context is

*The optimism and (the) strong will(s) of the handicapped children touched me deeply.*

Also, do I need a "the" before "strong will(s)" in this sentence?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it's General Reference for [linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) that "will" in such contexts can be singular *or* plural, depending on whether you're thinking of a the children as numerous individuals with separate characters and attitudes, or as a single group having a shared perspective on life. And it's just a stylistic choice whether to "delete" the second instance of the word ***the***. But you might consider asking such things on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks @FumbleFingers. I didn't know the Q&A site you mentioned.

Comment: Strong will = strong testes. Strong wills = strong testates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do not have distinct individual shades of optimism or of will. All they have is the same optimism and the same will.

A plural is thus symantically incorrect without doubt here.

> The optimism and **the strong will** of the handicapped children touched me deeply.

Furthermore, it is their **presence**, not the optimism and will by themselves, that is the subject of the sentence.

The definite article **is** required before *strong*.

---

As an aside,
*handicapped* may be avoided as far as possible: try alternatives like *differently-abled* or just *different*.

Answer (score 0):

I think both are acceptable. Each handicapped child has their own strong will so you can refer to each child's strong will individually with the plural usage, or you could refer to their collective strong will in the singular form. However, you refer to their optimism collectively so it may be best to refer to their strong will collectively as well.

As for the "the", I think its acceptable either way, but I personally think it sounds better to omit it, especially when referring to both collectively.

So basically I think whichever way you phrase it would probably not be incorrect, but for good style I suggest:

"The optimism and strong will of the handicapped children touched me deeply."